# NA after normalization in R

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe called 'weather' that I am trying to normalize:

```
'data.frame':   4745 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ TimeofDay    : int  700 800 900 1000 1100 1200 1300 1400 1500 1600 ...
 $ AirTemp      : num  16.4 17.7 19.3 19.8 21.3 ...
 $ Humidity     : num  76.3 68.5 57.4 53.6 49.2 ...
 $ Dewpoint     : num  12.2 11.8 10.7 10.2 10.2 ...
 $ BarPres      : num  101 101 101 101 101 ...
 $ MaxWindSpeed : num  4.45 5.25 5.25 6.85 5.25 ...
 $ Zenith       : num  99 88.4 81.7 72.2 64.5 59.2 57.1 58.4 63 70.3 ...
 $ Azimuth      : num  -99 119 125 135 148 ...
 $ TotalSolarRad: int  0 2 77 116 76 93 138 125 138 82 ...
```

I am using the standard normalization function as follows:

```
normalize <- function(x) {
    return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
  }
```

and applying it like this:

```
weatherNorm <- as.data.frame(lapply(weather, normalize))
```

after normalization the new dataframe is composed of numerous NA values like these:

```
'data.frame':   4745 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ TimeofDay    : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ AirTemp      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Humidity     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Dewpoint     : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ BarPres      : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ MaxWindSpeed : num  NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA NA ...
 $ Zenith       : num  1 0.879 0.803 0.695 0.607 ...
 $ Azimuth      : num  0 0.562 0.577 0.604 0.635 ...
 $ TotalSolarRad: num  0 0.00199 0.07669 0.11554 0.0757 ...
```

Is there any reason why the function would change the values to NA? The function works as needed on other dataframes as required.

Comment: See `?max`. You want `na.rm`.

Comment: Post a reproducible example instead of `str`

Comment: Also I'd do: `r <- range(x, na.rm = TRUE); return((x - r[1])/diff(r))` -- you're calculating `min` twice

Answer (score 3):

The problem here is that your vector contains NA values. Using min() and max() for vectors containing NA values returns NA. There is an optional parameter in min() and max() which is na.rm which is set to FALSE by default. 
This paramter when set to true lets min() and max() skip over NA values. Thus in this case change your function to

```
normalize <- function(x) {
return ((x - min(x, na.rm = TRUE)) / (max(x, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x, na.rm = TRUE)))}
```

Answer (score 1):

`max()`, and `min()` need to be used with `na.rm = T` to "skip" over `NA` values when calculating their respective result.

Comment: so where do I need to add the na.rm = T?