# Normalization of dataset with numeric and factors before KNN in r

Tags: r, normalization, knn

I am trying to analyze my first dataset. I want to preform KNN at the set, but having a hard time finding a way to normalize it. It contains 20 variables and 30k observations. The variables are both factors and numeric. I have understood that I have to create my own function two do this?

Can someone help me create a recipe for normalization of a dataset with both numeric and factors? It would be really helpful!

Some more information: 
I have taken out 7 variables from the dataset. age(int), martial(factor, 3 levels), education(factor, 11 levels), housing ( factor 2, levels), contact (factor, 2 levels) and income (int).

What I have thought of so fare is to concert all variable to numeric, and then normalize it to a value between 0 and 1. I have understood that this is required since my original data(/values) is not consistent. Ex: Age is between 7 and 86, and income is between $0-$130 000, and I have som factors as well.

## First I convert my variables to numeric:

```
df=data.frame(as.numeric(as.factor(df$age)),
                    as.numeric(as.factor(df$job)),
                    as.numeric(as.factor(df$marital)),
                    as.numeric(as.factor(df$education)),
                    as.numeric(as.factor(df$housing)),
                    as.numeric(as.factor(df$contact)),
                    as.numeric(as.factor(df$income))
```

## Then changing colnames back to what is was before converting.

```
colnames(df)=c("age","job","marital","education","housing","contact",
                     "income")
```

## Then I have found this funtion that I have tried to apply to the set.

```
normalize <- function(x) {
    return ((x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)))
  }

dfnormlize <- as.data.frame(lapply(df, normalize))
```

After that I am a little bit lost, since I can't get it to work.

Comment: It's more likely that we will be able to help you if you provide [a complete minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to go along with your question. Something we can work from and use to show you how it might be possible to answer your question. I will also recommend to take a look at this post; [_how do I ask a good question_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). It's generally good to demonstrate you already put some effort into it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [NA after normalization in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36389480/na-after-normalization-in-r)

Comment: Have edit som additional information now.

Comment: great job. You got  my vote!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Can I ask u an additional question? When normalize for KNN. Is it correct to convert my factors to numeric before carry out the normalization?

Answer (score 1):

It would help if you provided an example of your data and indicated what you have tried. I will take a jab at an answer with the information that you have provided. Hopefully this gets at what you are after.

First, we create a data.frame with one factor, one integer and two numeric columns.

```
   d <- data.frame(x=runif(10), f=as.factor(rep("X", 10)), y=runif(10),
                i=as.integer(c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5))))
```

We can then create an index that indicate which columns are numeric and integer. Depending on the nature of the integer column, you may want to omit it from normalization but, I wanted to provide an example that would catch something other than numeric.

```
( nidx <- grep(paste(c("numeric","integer"), collapse="|"), lapply(d, class)) )
```

Now we can use the index to operate on, and replace, columns that are numeric.

```
d[,nidx] <- scale(d[,nidx]) 
str( d )
```

If you wanted to apply a function to each column you could use a for loop on the column index or simply use `apply`.

```
norm <- function(x) { (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) }

  for(i in nidx) { d[,i] <- norm( d[,i] ) }         # example 1

  d[,nidx] <- apply(d[,nidx], MARGIN=2, FUN=norm ) # example 2
```

To put this into a single example

```
d <- data.frame(x=runif(10), f=as.factor(rep("X", 10)), y=runif(10),
                i=as.integer(c(rep(1,5), rep(2,5))))
( nidx <- grep(paste(c("numeric","integer"), collapse="|"), lapply(d, class)) )
norm <- function(x) { (x - min(x)) / (max(x) - min(x)) } 
d[,nidx] <- apply(d[,nidx], MARGIN=2, FUN=norm )
str(d)
```

Comment: Thanks! I have added some additional information in the main question now. Do this provide you with what you need as an example of my data?

Comment: Thanks! It worked! One more question. Is it ok that I am converting all factors to numeric before using your function to normalize ? In terms of performing KNN afterwards.

Comment: The factor value or level is quite irrelevant in deriving the multivariate distances used in kNN. So no, coercing your factors to numeric is not valid. There are clustering methods that allow for factors but, k-means is not one of them.